# Spring pass a component as an argument in method

Tags: spring

I have a spring `bean` that is a factory for services. Something like this:

```
public abstract class Serivce {
     public abstract Type getType();
}
```

concrete implementations:

```
@Service
public class CarService extends Service {}

@Service
public class BicycleService extends Service {}
```

And the factory bean:

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactory {
     private final Map<Type, Service> typeToService = new HashMap<>();

    //Autowire'ing services here
    //get concrete service method here
}
```

Further in my code I have something like this:

```
@Autowired
public ServiceFactory  factory;

public void methodA(Type type) {
    Service service = factory.getFor(type);
    service.baseMethod();

    methodB(type);
}

public void methodB(Type type) {
    Service service = factory.getFor(type);
    serivce.otherBaseMethod();
}
```

Like you see, I have to call `factory` bean in `methodB` for the second time. Can I pass `service` instance to `methodB()` instead of the `type` ? to avoid second call to factory ? Is it safe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `otherBaseMethod()` is stateless (doesn't set/maintain a state inside the `Service` instance) you can pass a bean instance as a parameter of the `methodB()` method without any thread-safety issue such as :

```
public void methodA(Type type) {
    Service service = factory.getFor(type);
    service.baseMethod();    
    methodB(service);
}

private void methodB(Service service) {
    service.otherBaseMethod();
}
```

As a side note, I changed the modifier to private for `methodB()` since the bean parameter should be only provided by the class members to be consistent with your use case.

Interleaved invocations of `otherBaseMethod()` will indeed have no side effects between them.
That is not specific to Spring. That is Java specific. Since in Spring we are encouraged to define Spring services as much stateless as possible (once the bean created), that means that generally interleaved invocations is generally not an issue.